# Asp.net MVC .properties file is not loading from View(cshtml)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I am doing an asp.net mvc project.In the view(cshtml) page, I have to load several external resources with several extensions.All the resources with extensions **.css**,**.js** are loading.But, I have a file has the extension **.properties** which is not being loaded in same process.I don't know how to solve it.

The error is -

**Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)**

My project structure

```
-Project
    -Areas
        -Two
            -Library
                -pdfjs-1.5.188-dist
                    -web
                        -locale
                            -locale.properties
```

I am using following line to load **locale.properties** file i the view -

```
<link rel="resource" type="application/l10n" href="~/Areas/Two/Library/pdfjs-1.5.188-dist/web/locale/locale.properties">
```

The given path is 100% correct.But, on that path resource is not being found.

Can anybody say me what is the problem and how can I solve this???

Comment: Is that a java file?

Comment: I am not sure ..... the file name is 'locale' and extension is 'properties'

Here are two lines from that file, 

    [ach]
    @import url(ach/viewer.properties)

This file import many properties file in his own.

Comment: Make sure you have the following block of code in your web.config `<system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
        <remove fileExtension=".application" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".application" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
    </staticContent>
</system.webServer>`

Answer (score 5):

You have to add the `.properties` file extension to your `web.config` file:

```
<system.webServer>
  <staticContent>
    <remove fileExtension=".properties" />
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".properties" mimeType="text/plain" />
  </staticContent>
</system.webServer>
```